# Radius of the water level in terms of the height of the water in a cone

Tags: calculus, geometry

When looking at the solution online for Apostol's Calculus's 4.12.25 question, I found this description of the radius of the water level in terms of the height of the water in a right circular cone.
[image]
[image]

Why do they have opposite signs?And how to know which should be negative and which should be positive?

Comment: At an intuitive level, the radius should be linearly associated with the height.  Can you clarify what you are asking?  Do you have a more specific reference to the problem you are working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because as the water enters the cone, in one case the radius at the surface *increases* (the surface area gets larger) and in the other it *decreases* (the surface area gets smaller).

Nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MateusBarbosa:  Gosh... so no acceptance?  Not even an upvote??

Comment: Haha, sorry. I tried looking for a solved button, but couldn't find it. And I did upvote you, but I'm new in this website so it isn't displayed.